# Translate a list of time punches into time worked by hour in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime, lambda

I have a List objects that detail clock punches for workers that looks like this:

```
Person  Time     Action
Cindy   07:00    clockin
Jim     08:12    clockin
Cindy   11:15    startlunch
Cindy   12:12    endlunch
Jim     12:30    startlunch
Jim     12:55    endlunch
Cindy   15:30    clockout
Jim     17:00    clockout
```

Of course the real data is hundreds of people and it is broken out by department, etc.

They want me to to create a report that shows how much labor is worked for each hour in the day. The end result Should look like this:

```
Time   Worked
7-8      1
8-9      1.8
9-10     2
10-11    2
11-12    1.25
12-1     1.3
etc.
```

As an interum step, I have converted the series of punches to a List of WorkRecords and it looks like this:

```
Person     In      Out
Cindy      07:00  11:15 
Jim        08:22  12:30
Cindy      12:12  15:30
Jim        12:55  17:00
```

I was thinking about looping through all the hours and testing each WorkRecord if it includes time with in a given hour, but that seems cumbersome.

Is there a more elegant way to reorganize my data into my final product using lambda or linq expressions?  It could start with the original data or the interum.  Thank you for look into this puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt with LINQ.

I assume that your `WorkRecord` is something like this.

```cs
    public  class WorkRecord
    {
        public readonly String name;
        public readonly DateTime StarTime;
        public readonly DateTime EndTime;

        public WorkRecord(string name, DateTime starTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            this.name = name;
            StarTime = starTime;
            EndTime = endTime;
        }

        public WorkRecord(string name, string starTime, string endTime)
        {
            this.name = name;
            StarTime = DateTime.ParseExact(starTime, "HH:mm", null);
            EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(endTime, "HH:mm", null);
        }
    }
```

It is not clear if they are already pre-filtered for single day or not. I'll try to cover both cases (but still simplistic)

```cs
    public  class DayStats
    {
        public readonly int[] TotalMinutes = new int[24];

        public void AddWorkRecord(WorkRecord record)
        {
            // Note: this method doesn't handle case when EndTime is next day
            // handle "middle" hours, they are all full
            for (int hour = record.StarTime.Hour + 1; hour < record.EndTime.Hour; hour++)
            {
                TotalMinutes[hour] += 60;
            }
            // handle first and last hours that might be not full
            if (record.StarTime.Hour == record.EndTime.Hour)
            {
                TotalMinutes[record.StarTime.Hour] += record.EndTime.Minute - record.StarTime.Minute;
            }
            else
            {
                TotalMinutes[record.StarTime.Hour] += 60 - record.StarTime.Minute;
                TotalMinutes[record.EndTime.Hour] += record.EndTime.Minute;
            }
        }

        public string AsPrettyString()
        {
            return string.Join("\n", TotalMinutes
                .Select((totalMinutes, hour) => string.Format("{0}-{1} {2}", hour, hour + 1, totalMinutes)));
        }
    }

    public class TimeCardAggregate
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<DateTime, DayStats> _days = new Dictionary<DateTime, DayStats>();

        public void AddWorkRecord(WorkRecord record)
        {
            // Note: this method doesn't handle case when EndTime is next day
            var date = record.StarTime.Date;
            DayStats dayStats;
            if (!_days.TryGetValue(date, out dayStats))
            {
                dayStats = new DayStats();
                _days.Add(date, dayStats);
            }
            dayStats.AddWorkRecord(record);
        }

        public List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, DayStats>> GetTimecard()
        {
            return _days.ToList().OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).ToList();
        }
    }
```

`DayStats` represents aggregated result for single day. `TimeCardAggregate` is result for several days. Most of the work is done by helper methods `AddWorkRecord` in both classes which you can use from `Aggregate` LINQ method. See how you can use them:

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<WorkRecord> records = new List<WorkRecord>
        {
            new WorkRecord("Cindy", "07:00", "11:15"),
            new WorkRecord("Jim", "08:22", "12:30"),
            new WorkRecord("Jim", "12:12", "15:30"),
            new WorkRecord("Cindy", "12:55", "17:00")
        };

        var dayStats = records.Aggregate(new DayStats(), (ds, wr) =>
        {
            ds.AddWorkRecord(wr);
            return ds;
        });

        Console.WriteLine(dayStats.AsPrettyString());



        List<WorkRecord> recordsForTwoDays = new List<WorkRecord>();
        recordsForTwoDays.AddRange(records);
        // just copy the data for the next day
        recordsForTwoDays.AddRange(records.Select(wr => new WorkRecord(wr.name, wr.StarTime.AddDays(1), wr.StarTime.AddDays(1))));
        var timecard = recordsForTwoDays.Aggregate(new TimeCardAggregate(), (ds, wr) =>
        {
            ds.AddWorkRecord(wr);
            return ds;
        });
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");


        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n-------------\n", timecard.GetTimecard().Select(kv =>
        {
            return kv.Key.ToShortDateString() + ":\n" + dayStats.AsPrettyString();
        })));
    }
```

Note also, that both implementations of `AddWorkRecord` are naive and don't handle the case when someone worked over night and have a record spawning over several days. It is not very hard to fix though.